# Google Spreadsheet Menu Buttons Disabled (Grayed Out)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am using Google Spreadsheets to build a simple tool that writes out a hardcoded message on my sheet. I am transferring it to another user. In their system, however, we are not seeing the 'Script Editor' option in any of the dropdown menus. Moreover, some options are disabled/grayed out on that system:

[image: Disabled Google Sheets menu items]

They are also not able to invoke the buttons when called. I am able to run this tool on my other IDs however.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? (I've provided edit access to the other user as well)

Comment: Is the other user logged in to their Google account? This occurs when either the user isn't logged in to the correct account (or at all!), or only view access is given.

Comment: Hi, it is an organization account (xxx@org.com), and linked to GCP - does that qualify as a google account?

Comment: That does qualify; as long as the account is what is used to log in to google.com, then it is. I suspect your user is not logged into the right account. Can you share your share settings? Sanitise the information first, of course.

Comment: Thanks @RafaGuillermo for your inputs. The issue was with the firewalls installed on the system through her organization's IT team. It has been resolved now :)

Comment: I have the same issue and there's no firewalls. A personal Gmail account can see those menus, but a Workspace account can't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a spreadsheet opened by a Google Workspace account user. The <kbd>Format</kbd> and <kbd>Extensions</kbd> menu entries were disabled, along with formatting toolbar icons:

[image: Format and Extensions menus disabled]

But the same spreadsheet when **opened by my consumer/personal Google account**, had all the menu items and toolbar icons enabled as usual.

I don't know what the cause is. The spreadsheet was created by going to <kbd>File -> Make a copy</kbd> in a spreadsheet received from a Google Workspace user by my personal account. My personal account then shared the copy with an account in a different Google Workspace org, as an **Editor**. Both accounts were logged in at the same time but opening the spreadsheet in an incognito window with only my different Workspace account logged in, didn't help (the menus were still grayed out). No apps/add-ons are installed in my Workspace account. I tried sharing the spreadsheet with both an admin and a regular Workspace account as **Editor**s and both had the same disabled menu items.

Making a copy of the copy didn't help. <kbd>Extensions -> Apps Script</kbd> showed no code.

The only workaround if I wanted to make edits was to open the spreadsheet with my personal account, or copy/paste everything into a spreadsheet created by my Workspace account.